# How to upgrade into ionic2 rc1 application

Tags: angular, ionic2, tsconfig

I've done all the upgrade steps , after step 26. "Delete the typings/ folder and typings.json file" I get error on files which includes "Promise" type . the error is "corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json" .

Comment: Could you add more context please ? Step 26 of what ?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#steps-to-upgrade-to-rc0

Comment: Probably easiest way is generating a new project from scratch and copying your page to the src folder (following the steps in that github)

Comment: As soon as I introduce "Promise" into code , same problem appears.